# Check a variable after call it PHP

Tags: php

I have a varaible:

```
$this->valuepicname = isset($_POST['picname'][$numberpicname]) ? $_POST['picname'][$numberpicname] : "";
```

The varabile $numberpicname is static and each time I call to - it has another value, so, I want to do it too with th varaible $valuepicname - but I can't define it as static ($valuepicname) because its IF statement (i think this is the reason..).

Hope you understand.. (my english is bad)
Thank you.

Comment: no, sorry, I don't understand the question. But I can tell you that I don't see anything wrong with that line of code. If you post more code, maybe we can see something wrong.

Comment: It's not clear what are you after. Being able to have static valuepicname?

Comment: Well, I just need when I call to the varabile 'valuepicname' => it checks it and his value because it changes all the time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

object values in PHP can't be both static and dynamic, which is what you are trying to do by setting it with a boolean. Also, if you want it to be static, why are you calling it using $this?

Answer (score 0):

```
define("STATIC_STRING", "what ever you want here");
define("STATIC_INT", 100);
define("STATIC_BOOL", TRUE);

if(STATIC_BOOL) {
  echo "We have static!!!<br />\n";
}

if(STATIC_INT === 100) {
  echo "We have static!!!<br />\n";
}

if(STATIC_STRING != "") {
  echo "We have static!!!<br />\n";
}
```

Something like this?

```
$this->valuepicname = STATIC_BOOL;
```